# Show text with hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to show some text when I put the mouse hover an image. Actually I already made this working but the text was rising the size of the card, this is why I added a `display none` to the text class.

I can't really put all the code here, let me give you a snipped from jsfiddle it will be easier: https://jsfiddle.net/Minirock/fgs7o2Lv/1/
The text I would like to show is under the FORUM 1 and FORUM 2 into the fiddle sample.

Please let me know if you need more explanation about what is wrong. The html unit code is under.

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="forum_title">FORUM 1</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 category">
            <div class="card card-chart image1">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/150/nature/" alt="avatar_monde" class="img_monde" />
                    <div class="middle">
                        <div class="text">Post haec Gallus Hierapolim profecturus ut expeditioni specie tenus adesset, Antiochensi plebi suppliciter obsecranti ut inediae dispelleret metum.</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 category">
            <div class="card card-chart detail">
                NOM SUJET
                <br/>
                NOM POSTEUR
                <br/>
                HEURE
                <br/>
                <a href="#"> > LIRE LE DERNIER MESSAGE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting your styles on `.middle`: https://jsfiddle.net/3me1t42w/

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
.text{
    display: none;
}
```

with this (and should work without any issue)

```
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I had something like that in the begenning too, but if I do that the text isn't fully seen. I would like to have it on the upper left corner of the picture. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used to face such problem before.It is an easy fix.While not do

```
.text{
    display:none;
}

.image1:hover .middle,
.image2:hover .middle,
.image3:hover .middle ,
.image4:hover .middle ,
.image5:hover .middle ,
.image6:hover .middle ,
.image7:hover .middle ,
.image8:hover .middle ,
.image9:hover .middle ,
.image10:hover .middle ,
.image11:hover .middle ,
.image12:hover .middle ,
.image13:hover .middle ,
.image14:hover .middle ,
.image15:hover .middle 
{
     opacity: 1;
     display:block;
}
```

Note that the text class must be in the same div as the images.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jQuery for this by simply using the onmouseover event

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.img_monde').mouseover(function(){
   $('.text').css('display', 'inline');
})
</script>
```

This checks for a mouseover event on the image with class "img_monde" and sets the display of the div with class "text" to inline when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your style on the division tag middle